# Скрыть клавиатуру при нажатии за пределы EditText

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, ontouchlistener

Пишу приложение для Андроида и возник вопрос, как скрыть клавиатуру при нажатии вне `EditText`?

Насколько я читал можно это делать через `OnTouchListener`? Тогда вопрос в том, как его повесить на `LinearLayout`?

Пишу в Xamarin на C#. Собственно, мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;


namespace MurakamiKiev
{
    [Activity(Label = "Murakami", Icon = "@drawable/logo", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class Cart2Activity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden);



            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Cart2);
            ImageButton nadislati = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.nadislatiButton);
            ImageButton logo = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.logoButton);
            ImageButton previous = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.previousButton);
            ImageButton home = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeButton);
            ImageButton menu = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.menuButton);

            //EditText misto = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.misto);


            nadislati.Click += delegate
            {
                var intent31 = new Intent(this, typeof(Cart3Activity));
                StartActivity(intent31);
            };
            previous.Click += delegate
            {
                var intent32 = new Intent(this, typeof(CartActivity));
                StartActivity(intent32);
            };
            //Otslezivaem click po knopke "Home" i perehodim na glavnuu
            home.Click += delegate
            {
                var intent33 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(intent33);
            };
            //Otslezivaem click po knopke "Logo" i perehodim na glavnuu
            logo.Click += delegate
            {
                var intent34 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(intent34);
            };
            menu.Click += delegate
            {
                var intent51 = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuTopActivity));
                StartActivity(intent51);

            };
        }
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {

            EditText misto = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.misto);
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);

            inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);

            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Рекомендую вам выбрать один вопрос и сосредоточиться на нем. Про Java можете спросить отдельно, с кодом на Java.

Comment: Ок. Какова реализация в c#?

Comment: Ещё подсказка на будущее: вы там в редакторе нажали кнопку с `<>` для оформления кода. Она только для сниппетов на JS-HTML-CSS, которые могут прямо в браузере выполняться. Для обычного кода используйте кнопку `{}`, или просто отступ в 4 пробела. Пока что я отредактировал ответ, поправив форматирование.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно проблема решена

1. Для того чтобы  клавиатура не выпадала в EditText при запуске надо вставить этот код:

   ```
   Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden);
   ```
2. Для закрытия клавиатуры при нажатии на другой элемент на экране
   вешаем на него .Click по которому закрываем клавиатуру

   ```
   one.Click += delegate
       {
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
           imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(misto.WindowToken, 0);
       };
   ```